# Automate Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am trying to see how I can change this macro and make it so that it will run Power Query below, but for all files in the same folder the excel is in. In this example #3 is the file name that would need to change each time it loops to a new file.

```vb
Sub Get_Data()

    ExecuteExcel4Macro _
        "(""#3"",""let" & Chr(10) & "  Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""/Users/tmayfield/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Glaeser Park Territories/New Locations/#3.xlsx""), null, true)," & Chr(10) & "  Navigation = Source{[Item = ""#3"", Kind = ""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(10) & "  #""Promoted headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Navigation, [PromoteAllScalars = true])," & Chr(10) & "  #""Changed column type"" = Table.Trans" & _
        "formColumnTypes(#""Promoted headers"", {{""#"", type text}, {""Street "", type text}, {""Number"", Int64.Type}, {""Status"", type any}, {""Date"", type any}})" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(10) & "  #""Changed column type"""")" & _
        ""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=#3;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [#3]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_ExternalData_2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to combine modern Power Query with ancient Excel 4 macros? Maybe take a step back and explain what you're trying to achieve overall, then we can help you find a modern way to do that.

Comment: this is the output the record macro produce. as I stated I want to be able to view all my excels from one excel using power query